# How to merge json string and give new alias and remove old key in Python

Tags: python

I have Some of the data that have nested attribute and need to combine and give new alias also remove the old one.

Sample Data:

```
[
   {
      "model.code":{
         "model":{
            "code":"Z15"
         }
      }
   },
   {
      "model.name":{
         "model":{
            "name":"Test"
         }
      }
   }
]
```

Expected Output:

```
[
   {
      "model":{
         "code":"Z15",
         "name":"Test"
      }
   }
]
```

How can acheived this using python

Comment: You have tagged the question with python but added no code.

Comment: The way you do this will depend upon what you know about the original dictionary. Do you know for example, that model.code and model.name exist (always)?

Comment: No this field is not always exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this by using `jsonmerge`:

```
from jsonmerge import merge

d1 ={
      "model.code":{
         "model":{
            "code":"Z15"
         }
      }
   }
d2 = {
      "model.name":{
         "model":{
            "name":"Test"
         }
      }
   }

result = merge(d1["model.code"], d2["model.name"])
```

```
>>> result
{'model': {'code': 'Z15', 'name': 'Test'}}
```

for more complex use cases check [Project Description](https://pypi.org/project/jsonmerge/).